# Cant host server on Android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I get two Android emulators to connect to each other?
I'm trying to make a card game app where one device is the Server host and the other device connects to it. The problem right now is, that in Android studio I get a "java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable" error.

I "tried" something with "telnet" but I dont know what telnet is so I can't use it properly.
I also tried adding a new firewall rule but here also , I dont know how to work with firewalls.
So if someone could explain me how to get two Android emulators connect to each other, that would be nice.
(I'm trying to use port 56564 but I also dont know much about ports so does someone know if I can use this port?)

Comment: Are you using an ip address? Do!

Comment: Switch off the firewall during tests.

Comment: `how to get two Android emulators connect to each other, ` Hey you should have started with that. Forget it. Use two devices.

Comment: Turning off the firewall didn't work. Still the same Exception

Comment: I found out the solution! I was trying to connect to the devices IP-address, but in fact you have to connect to 10.0.2.2, a  loopback IP from the emulator to find your pc (it says it right in there in the developer documentation on https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking but I overread it duh)